# problems with python curve fit : horizontal line

Tags: python, line, curve, data-fitting

I can't manage to fit my points with an equation.
It plots a horizontal line.
I have the impression that it comes from the initial parameters but I don't know what to put.
I took this piece of code from another forum.
At first, everything works well but when I enter new data, there is a problem.

Can someone help me, please ?

```
***import numpy as np, scipy, matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
from scipy.optimize import differential_evolution
import warnings
xData = np.array([.26, .35, .36, .37, .42, .46, .48, .54, .59, .72, .74, .83, .88, 1.04, 1.10, 1.12, 1.48])
yData = np.array([27.40, 29.96, 27.50, 28.20, 32.47, 31.52, 31.00, 34.93, 32.80, 35.84, 39.50, 40.00, 41.35, 41.50, 42.79, 41.71, 46.23])
 
def func(x, a, b, Offset): # Sigmoid A With Offset from zunzun.com
    return  1.0 / (1.0 + np.exp(-a * (x-b))) + Offset
# function for genetic algorithm to minimize (sum of squared error)
def sumOfSquaredError(parameterTuple):
    warnings.filterwarnings("ignore") # do not print warnings by genetic algorithm
    val = func(xData, *parameterTuple)
    return np.sum((yData - val) ** 2.0)
# generate initial parameter values
geneticParameters = [0,0,0] 
# curve fit the test data
fittedParameters, pcov = curve_fit(func, xData, yData, geneticParameters)
print('Parameters', fittedParameters)
modelPredictions = func(xData, *fittedParameters) 
absError = modelPredictions - yData
SE = np.square(absError) # squared errors
MSE = np.mean(SE) # mean squared errors
RMSE = np.sqrt(MSE) # Root Mean Squared Error, RMSE
Rsquared = 1.0 - (np.var(absError) / np.var(yData))
print('RMSE:', RMSE)
print('R-squared:', Rsquared)
##########################################################
# graphics output section
def ModelAndScatterPlot(graphWidth, graphHeight):
    f = plt.figure(figsize=(graphWidth/100.0, graphHeight/100.0), dpi=100)
    axes = f.add_subplot(111)
    # first the raw data as a scatter plot
    axes.plot(xData, yData,  'D')
    # create data for the fitted equation plot
    xModel = np.linspace(min(xData), max(xData))
    yModel = func(xModel, *fittedParameters)
    # now the model as a line plot 
    axes.plot(xModel, yModel)
    axes.set_xlabel('X Data') # X axis data label
    axes.set_ylabel('Y Data') # Y axis data label
    plt.show()
   # plt.close('all') # clean up after using pyplot
graphWidth = 400
graphHeight = 300
ModelAndScatterPlot(graphWidth, graphHeight)***
```

Comment: your fit is most probably not converging. Try to find better start Parameters

Comment: your main problem is that your fit function only has an amplitude of 1 while your data span is about 20. You are missing an amplitude parameter.

Answer (score 1):

The most probable cause of the failure is that you chose a three parameters (a,b,offset) sigmoid model instead of a four parameters model. The range of the data from 27.4 to 46.23 never can be fitted to a function which range is from 0 to 1, even with an offset.

Another possible cause of difficulty is the initial guessing of the values of the parameters in starting the iterrative process of the non-linear regression.

In order to avoid those difficulties we will use the non-iterative method shown below.

Note that the symbols and notations are not the same as in your code.

[image]

[image]

You can use the above numerical values of the parameters as initial values in your non-linear regression software.

Note : The general principle of the non-iterative method is explained in the paper : https://fr.scribd.com/doc/14674814/Regressions-et-equations-integrales

The above calculus is a simplified version of the application to the four parameters logistic regression.